# Logarithmic Y axis in Highcharts 3.0 bubble chart

Tags: highcharts, logarithm, bubble-chart

I'm trying to change yAxis type of a Highcharts 3.0ß bubble chart to logarithmic, but - when it displays something - it displays a single series, and a single bubble... here's an simple example, based on "official" bubble chart demo : http://jsfiddle.net/FtdYf/

```
$(function() {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts bubbles with radial gradient fill'
    },

    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        type:'logarithmic'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            [9, 81, 63],
            [98, 5, 89],
            [51, 50, 73],
            [41, 22, 14],
            [58, 24, 20],
            [78, 37, 34],
            [55, 56, 53],
            [18, 45, 70],
            [42, 44, 28],
            [3, 52, 59],
            [31, 18, 97],
            [79, 91, 63],
            [93, 23, 23],
            [44, 83, 22]
        ],
        marker: {
             fillColor: {
                 radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                 stops: [
                     [0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'],
                     [1, 'rgba(69,114,167,0.5)']
                 ]
             }
        }
    }, {
        data: [
            [42, 38, 20],
            [6, 18, 1],
            [1, 93, 55],
            [57, 2, 90],
            [80, 76, 22],
            [11, 74, 96],
            [88, 56, 10],
            [30, 47, 49],
            [57, 62, 98],
            [4, 16, 16],
            [46, 10, 11],
            [22, 87, 89],
            [57, 91, 82],
            [45, 15, 98]
        ],
        color: 'rgba(170,70,67,0.5)',
        marker: {

             fillColor: {
                 radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                 stops: [
                     [0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'],
                     [1, 'rgba(170,70,67,0.5)']
                 ]
             }
        }
    }]

});
});
```

So here's my question : is logarithmic axis (X and Y) possible on a bubble chart, and if so, why do it displays just a single series and a single bubble ?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

You can set `tickPositions` or create your own `tickPositioner`. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/FtdYf/2/